# kendo ui angular split panel change background color

Tags: css, angular, kendo-ui

I have tried to change the background color for a 
kendo-splitter-pane. However even if I add a style tag to it, it does not seem to apply to its inner elements.

What is then the appropriate way to customize the color for a kendo-splitter-pane?

Comment: kindly  [**create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to apply the `background-color` on the `kendo-splitter-pane` element, like this:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `
        <kendo-splitter style="height: 200px;">
            <kendo-splitter-pane class="pane1">
                <h3>Left pane</h3>
            </kendo-splitter-pane>

            <kendo-splitter-pane>
                <h3>Center pane</h3>
            </kendo-splitter-pane>

            <kendo-splitter-pane [resizable]="false">
                <h3>Right pane</h3>
            </kendo-splitter-pane>
        </kendo-splitter>
    `,
    styles: [ `
        h3 {
            font-size: 1.2em;
            padding: 10px;
        }

        .pane1 {
            background-color: red;
        }
    ` ]
})
class AppComponent {}
```